# How to get the length of a MySQL int field

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL table with int fields of different length:

[image: MySql mediumint and tinyint fields of different lenght]

How do I find out the length `(nav_parent = 4, nav_show = 2, nav_order = 2)`
with PHP PDO?

Answer (score 4):

This works in MySQL and is **not experimental**:

```
 $result = $this->query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table_name', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now you have the following informations:

```
[Field] => yourfieldname
[Type] => int(10)
[Null] => NO
[Key] => PRI
[Default] => 
[Extra] => auto_increment
```

You can extract the lenth form **[Type] => int(10)** like

```
preg_match('/\d+/', $col['Type'], $len); // gives you the number
```

**Whole example:**

```
$result = $pdo->query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM youTableName');

$columLen = array();

foreach($result as $key => $col){

  preg_match('/\d+/', $col['Type'], $len); // get the number out of 'int(10)'
  $len = (isset($len[0]))? $len[0] : '';   // is there a length? 
  $fieldname = $col['Field'];              // name of the column
  $columLen[$fieldname]  = $len;           // save it in array 
}

print_r($columLen);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [nav_parent] => 4
  [nav_show] => 1
  [nav_order] => 2
)
```

**Attention:**
Certain fieldtypes, like date, datetime or text won't show the value lenght.
Example: A field of type timestamp will show **"[Type] => timestamp"** and not **"[Type] => timestamp (12)"**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
```

For more information [check here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html)

Comment: Noop, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH will bring up NULL, also NUMERIC_PRECISION and NUMERIC_SCALE will not bring up the lenght, which I am looking for (4, 1, 2)

Answer (score 1):

There is the [getColumnMeta](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) experimental method. The example provided in the documentation appears to show what you are after

```
<?php
$select = $DB->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit');
$meta = $select->getColumnMeta(0);
var_dump($meta);
?>

array(6) {
  ["native_type"]=>
  string(7) "integer"
  ["flags"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "COUNT(*)"
  ["len"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["precision"]=>
  int(0)
  ["pdo_type"]=>
  int(2)
```

}